# Buttons using Ajax don't work on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

Here I am following Michael Hartl's famous Ruby on Rails Tutorials (Rails 3.2).
The section of "11.2.5 A working follow button with Ajax" works in local machine but doesn't work on Heroku. 
When I clicked the Follow or Unfollow buttons, nothing on the page would refresh. Though I can see the action was indeed invoked from the logs.

```
2012-02-22T04:05:17+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/relationships" for 67.188.133.121 at 2012-02-22 04:05:17 +0000
2012-02-22T04:05:17+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by RelationshipsController#create as JS
2012-02-22T04:05:17+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"nsYrHM0aLlEGoI19Zv8hImEmbfWPZ+gSy5xmgAV+V60=", "relationship"=>{"followed_id"=>"15"}, "commit"=>"Follow"}
2012-02-22T04:05:17+00:00 app[web.1]: Redirected to https://etl-rails32-tut-sample-app.herokuapp.com/users/15
2012-02-22T04:05:17+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [POST /relationships] invalidate, pass
2012-02-22T04:05:17+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 302 Found in 66ms (ActiveRecord: 61.2ms)
2012-02-22T04:05:17+00:00 heroku[router]: POST etl-rails32-tut-sample-app.herokuapp.com/relationships dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=75ms status=302 bytes=123
```

Then I had to manually click the refresh button of browser (FireFox 7.0) to refresh the entire page, and the button would be correctly toggled in the result.

The file, app / views / layouts / application.html.erb, is as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
    <%= render 'layouts/stylesheets' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
      <section class="round">
        <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
          <%= content_tag(:div, value, class: "flash #{key}") %>
        <% end %>
        <%= yield %>
      </section>
      <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
      <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just finished the uploading my code to heroku and the buttons work.  I'm a n00b at this as well.  My application.html.erb is pretty close to yours.  I looked at your site (looks very different from mine) and I get the same problem you are getting.  My logs show a difference (removed line headers):

```
Started POST "/relationships" for 1.1.9.1 at 2012-04-10 21:06:47 +0000
Processing by RelationshipsController#create as JS
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"jF6cuJakhooP/fIdfAhIfhy+Djgox3jukyJbm86UkVU=", "relationship"=>{"followed_id"=>"2"}, "commit"=>"Follow"}
Rendered users/_unfollow.html.erb (3.8ms)
Rendered relationships/create.js.erb (7.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 36ms (Views: 4.2ms | ActiveRecord: 24.1ms)
cache: [POST /relationships] invalidate, pass
POST strong-stone-3754.herokuapp.com/relationships dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=93ms status=200 bytes=584
```

Mine renders while yours redirects.

Don't know if it is significant but I snagged the .js from both your page and mine and did a wc on them.  They are more than a little different.

```
18    1559  120293 mine.js
18    1343   99603 yours.js
```

Perhaps the problem is in the view/relationships/create.js.erb?

```
$("#follow_form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('users/unfollow')) %>")
$("#followers").html('<%= @user.followers.count %>')
```

Or maybe the RelationshipsContoller's create and destroy methods should have the following to respond to AJAX requests:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to @user }
  format.js
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be late ad you may have found and answer but this fixed it for me.

If you are using coffee-rails gem move the coffee-rails gem outside of the assets group. I put it just under the jquery-rails gem (don't think that matters much), but after putting it outside assets group it worked in heroku.